# Cannot Install WYSIWYG Extension for Yii 2 Using Composer

Tags: php, yii, ckeditor, yii-extensions, yii2

I've tried to install CKEditor and Imperavi Redactor using composer.

For CKEditor I got this error:

```
$ sudo composer require "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" "*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget 0.1.1 requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> no matching package found.
    - 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget 0.1.0 requires ckeditor/ckeditor dev-full/stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget * -> satisfiable by 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget[0.1.0, 0.1.1].
```

Funny, coz I've put "yiisoft/yii2": "*" in my composer.json requirement

And this is the error for Imperavi Redactor:

```
$ sudo composer require asofter/yii2-imperavi-redactor "*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package asofter/yii2-imperavi-redactor could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

what should I do to be able to install one of them ?
thanks

Comment: Mhm, using CKEDITOR as native JS extension and not as Yii widget should be no problem for you. Btw. Yii is not any time up2date in common UI/JS-Libs. I prefer using the latest UI/JS-Libs.

Comment: Step 1: Add this "asofter/yii2-imperavi-redactor": "*" and "2amigos/yii2-leaflet-geosearch-plugin" : "*"  the require section of your application's composer.json file.

Step 2 : If your .phar file is inside the advance templete

./composer.phar update

if not 

path/to/composer.phar update


Some times it shows problem. Try moving vendor dir to some other place and then update composer

Answer (score 0):

For imperavi redactor use this command:

```
sudo composer require asofter/yii2-imperavi-redactor "dev-master"
```